# Prevent scroll in ViewPager when string is empty

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i trying to make a wizard when app is run on first time. I use custom `ViewPager` to disable scroll and scroll using button previous and next. I want show show Toast to warn user that him must be fill form when user click next button and the form is emtpy, but my code doesn't work

this is my custom `ViewPager`

```
package com.candlelightstudio.letsbesmartkid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class DisableScrollViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public DisableScrollViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

}
```

this is my next button `onClickListener`

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int page = wizard.getCurrentItem();
                if(page == 0 && (nama_dpn == null || nama_blkg == null)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lengkapi nama depan dan belakang", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    wizard.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                }

                if(page == 1 && jk == null || jk.equalsIgnoreCase("Pilih jenis kelamin")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pilih jenis kelamin", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    wizard.setCurrentItem(2, true);
                }

                if(wizard.getCurrentItem() == 2 && sekolah == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Masukkan nama sekolah kamu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    wizard.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true);
                }
            }
```

getItem() code

```
private int getItem(int i){
        return wizard.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }
```

this is my `PagerAdapter` class

```
private static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        private int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(position){
            case 0:
                return FragmentIsiNama_Nama.newInstance(0);
            case 1:
                return FragmentIsiNama_JenisKelamin.newInstance(1);
            case 2:
                return FragmentIsiNama_Sekolah.newInstance(2);
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE**
The String variable `nama_dpn, nama_blkg, jk, sekolah` value is from `EditText` in a `fragment`, i use method like this

```
private int getItem(int i){
        return wizard.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }

    void onNamaDepanChange(String nama_depan){
        this.nama_dpn = nama_depan;
    }
    void onNamaBelakangChange(String nama_belakang){
        this.nama_blkg = nama_belakang;
    }
    void onJenisKelaminChange(String gender){
        this.jk = gender;
    }
    void onSekolahChange(String sekolah){
        this.sekolah = sekolah;
    }
```

and in fragment, for example i will fill string nama_dpn. I do like this

```
nama_depan.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ((IsiNama_Activity)getActivity()).onNamaDepanChange(s.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
```

What's my wrong? :) Thank you

i edited like below but did not work too

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int page = wizard.getCurrentItem();
                if(page == 0 && (TextUtils.isEmpty(nama_dpn) || TextUtils.isEmpty(nama_blkg))){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lengkapi nama depan dan belakang", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    wizard.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                }

                if(page == 1 && (TextUtils.isEmpty(jk) || jk.equalsIgnoreCase("Pilih jenis kelamin"))){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pilih jenis kelamin", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    wizard.setCurrentItem(2, true);
                }

                if(wizard.getCurrentItem() == 2 && TextUtils.isEmpty(sekolah)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Masukkan nama sekolah kamu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    wizard.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true);
                }
            }
```

**CLOSED** 
I got the way, before it i dont think why i must use method `onNamaDepanChange();` and send value of `EditText` using this way `((IsiNama_Activity)getActivity()).onNamaDepanChange(s.toString());` . I just think i can set value of `nama_depan` variable using this way `((IsiNama_Activity)getActivity()).nama_depan = s.toString();` and it's WORK properly. change modifier of `nama_depan` to public of course.

And there is an error logic in my case. You can see in my `next.setOnClickListener()` function. every line in `if' will be executed, so for prevent scroll i won't i do like below

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int page = wizard.getCurrentItem();
                if(page == 0 && (nama_dpn == null || nama_blkg == null)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lengkapi nama depan dan belakang", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if(page == 0 && (nama_dpn != null || nama_blkg != null)){
                    wizard.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                }

                if(page == 1 && (jk == null || jk.equalsIgnoreCase("Pilih jenis kelamin"))){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pilih jenis kelamin", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if(page == 1 && (jk != null || !jk.equalsIgnoreCase("Pilih jenis kelamin"))){
                    wizard.setCurrentItem(wizard.getCurrentItem()+1, true);
                }

                if(page == 2 && sekolah == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Masukkan nama sekolah kamu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if(page == 2 && sekolah != null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sekolah : " + sekolah, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

Comment: nama_dpn and nama_blkg are EditTexts? In that case you should check its text, not only a null check. .e.g: TextUtils.isEmpty(nama_blkg.getText().toString)

Comment: @urudroid i had edited my post sir. Sorry i forget to explain about that variable

Comment: you are only null checking the Strings, if the user writes and then delete, your String would be not-null but empty, so (nama_dpn == null || nama_blkg == null) will return false in a case you don't want it to. Did you try to debug this? it is entering to the line wizard.setCurrentItem(1, true); ?

Comment: @urudroid thanks sir for your comment, i did tried your suggest but this is does not work too

Comment: can you debug the code and explain where it doesnt go as expected ?

Comment: Thanks urudroid & Mr DavidJhons, i am noob. i dont know about debug mode befor. I just tried it, and the result siad "VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader, String) line: not available[native method]" "source not found" and in outline tab said "An outline is not available". What the meaning of this debug result?

Comment: This case closed, i got the way

Comment: Then can you post the answer? It might be helpful for other people